# Changing margins for only 1 page destroys format

Tags: formatting, geometry, report

I have a page that has too many pictures so I change the margin settings

```
\newgeometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=0.1cm, top=0.1cm}
% insert image here
\resetgeometry
```

The problem is, when I do that, the text gets split to a different page. Like in the example below (blurred) there is a lot of white space remaining in the page. Latex would automatically put more text there to fill it up but because I used the geometry function it does not work anymore. How can i fix this ?

Basically, how can I have a large image that fit in 1 page using the margin settings and still have latex functioning properly ?

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{20}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\footnotesize $}X<{$}}}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10} & x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} & x_{15} & x_{16} & x_{17} & x_{18} & x_{19} & x_{20} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Ground Truth]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/ms.png}}}} \\
\hat{x_2} & \hat{x_3} & \hat{x_4} & \hat{x_5} & \hat{x_6} & \hat{x_7} & \hat{x_8} & \hat{x_9} & \hat{x_{10}} & \hat{x_{11}} & \hat{x_{12}} & \hat{x_{13}} & \hat{x_{14}} & \hat{x_{15}} & \hat{x_{16}} & \hat{x_{17}} & \hat{x_{18}} & \hat{x_{19}} & \hat{x_{20}} & \hat{x_{21}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/ms-rnn.png}}}} \\
\hat{x_2} & \hat{x_3} & \hat{x_4} & \hat{x_5} & \hat{x_6} & \hat{x_7} & \hat{x_8} & \hat{x_9} & \hat{x_{10}} & \hat{x_{11}} & \hat{x_{12}} & \hat{x_{13}} & \hat{x_{14}} & \hat{x_{15}} & \hat{x_{16}} & \hat{x_{17}} & \hat{x_{18}} & \hat{x_{19}} & \hat{x_{20}} & \hat{x_{21}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Variational Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/ms-vrnn.png}}}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt} \\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10} & x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} & x_{15} & x_{16} & x_{17} & x_{18} & x_{19} & x_{20} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Ground Truth]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/mm.png}}}} \\
\hat{x_2} & \hat{x_3} & \hat{x_4} & \hat{x_5} & \hat{x_6} & \hat{x_7} & \hat{x_8} & \hat{x_9} & \hat{x_{10}} & \hat{x_{11}} & \hat{x_{12}} & \hat{x_{13}} & \hat{x_{14}} & \hat{x_{15}} & \hat{x_{16}} & \hat{x_{17}} & \hat{x_{18}} & \hat{x_{19}} & \hat{x_{20}} & \hat{x_{21}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/mm-rnn.png}}}} \\
\hat{x_2} & \hat{x_3} & \hat{x_4} & \hat{x_5} & \hat{x_6} & \hat{x_7} & \hat{x_8} & \hat{x_9} & \hat{x_{10}} & \hat{x_{11}} & \hat{x_{12}} & \hat{x_{13}} & \hat{x_{14}} & \hat{x_{15}} & \hat{x_{16}} & \hat{x_{17}} & \hat{x_{18}} & \hat{x_{19}} & \hat{x_{20}} & \hat{x_{21}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\multicolumn{20}{c}{\subfloat[Variational Recurrent Neural Network]{{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results/mm-vrnn.png}}}} \\ \\[-7ex]
\noindent\rule{15cm}{0.4pt} \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{}
\label{fig:ood-ms}
\end{figure}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Isn't the desired command `\restoregeometry` and not `\resetgeometry`?  In any event, changing geometry will indeed force a page break.  Rather than using `geometry` changes to handle an oversized figure, there are other ways to temporarily relax margins for the figure (`\smash` for vertical, and `\makebox[\textwidth]{}` for horizontal, as examples).

Comment: how do i use \smash ? i tried encapsulating the entire \begin{figure} and end in \smash but i got an error

Comment: You cannot `\smash` a "float" like `figure`, but only the contents of it, such as the `\includegraphics` or the `tikzpicture`.  Additional spacing adjustments are likely required when you do so, because `\smash` literally treats its argument as if it had zero height and depth.

Comment: I would add that providing us with a minimum working example of code would make it easier for us to show how the example could be changed to make it work.  Without the concrete example, we are just talking in the abstract

Comment: i have added the block of code for the figure

Comment: You don't have to provide your contents for an MWE if you don't want to (blurred). Just use some dummy content like `\blindtext` and `example-image` which has roughly the same size as your graphic. But give us a complete MWE meaning it should include `\documentclass`, all necessary `\usepackage`s to reproduce your *example*, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

This shows an example of an easy approach using `\smash`. I use `\vbox to \textheight` to tell LaTeX that this figure will take a complete page so it doesn't place any other figures on this float page. In this approach you'd most likely have to adapt some lengths to make it fit your needs.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{floatpag}

\begin{document}
%your approach:
\blindtext
\newgeometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=0.1cm, top=0.1cm}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry
\blindtext
\clearpage

%different approach:
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[p]
  \thisfloatpagestyle{empty}%
  \centering
  \vbox to \textheight{%
    \vspace*{1.12\textheight}%
    \smash{\makebox[\textwidth]{%
      \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth,height=0.85\paperheight]{example-image}
    }}%
    \caption{foo bar}
  }%
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess I have to wrap mine around \begin{tabularx} ?

Comment: @kong yes, it does seem so. Just replace my `\includegraphics` with your `tabularx`. If this doesn't work, I won't put more effort into this as long as you don't provide a complete MWE.